# Log all arguments of a function without using argument names

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's assume I got the following function:

```
def do_something(arg_1, arg_2, arg_3):
    logger.info('arg_1: {0} arg_2: {1} arg_3: {2}'.format(arg_1, arg_2, arg_3))
    print('Doing something..')
```

Is there an elegant way to log all arguments of a function without listing argument names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the perfect time to delve into decorators, I believe. Take a look at the following:

```
def log_args(function):

    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        logger.info(', '.join(str(x) for x in args))
        return function(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

*The `@functools.wraps` line is optional*

Now decorate your functions like so:

```
@log_args
def do_something(arg1, arg2):
    print('doing something..')
```

Explanation: the `@log_args` line is the same as doing:

```
do_something = log_args(do_something)
```

Now this `log_args` takes the function and enters its local scope. Inside this scope, another function is defined called wrapper. This function contains the logger which formats the args into a string. Then the result of the function is returned from wrapper. To ensure that `do_something` is still a function, I return the `wrapper`. Now when `do_something` is called, wrapper is actually called and the process above occurs.

The reason why I used a decorator is because I can retain having the explicit names arguments in the function definition, however, within the decorator I can use `*args` which packs those arguments into a list even though the function itself only has named args. *Note: I'm not 100% sure about that last point about retaining arguments. In fact, I don't think it is true at all.*

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @NChauhan's answer, if you want to be able to log not just the values of positional arguments, but the names of the positional arguments and keyword arguments along with their given values and default values as well, so that:

```
@log_args
def do_something(arg_1, arg_2, arg_3='world'):
    pass

do_something(2, arg_2='hello')
```

can output:

```
do_something called with arg_1: 2, arg_2: 'hello', arg_3: 'world'
```

You can use `inspect.signature` with your decorator:

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps
def log_args(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        bound = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        bound.apply_defaults()
        print('{} called with {}'.format(func.__name__, ', '.join('{}: {}'.format(name, repr(value)) for name, value in bound.arguments.items())))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    sig = inspect.signature(func)
    return wrapper
```